# Map columns with list and return corresponding list

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({"a":["a","b","c"],"d":[1,2,3]})
```

Given an array `["a","b","c","c"]`, I want it to use to map col "a", and get output `[1,2,3,3]` which is from column "d". Is there a short way to do this without iterating the rows?

Comment: Is possible some values not match? If yes, what is expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with index by `a` converted to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
a = ["a","b","c","c"]

L = df.set_index('a').reindex(a)['d'].tolist()
print (L)
[1, 2, 3, 3]
```